# Eclipse Galileo SQL Editor: is there a code formatter (tidy) function?

Tags: sql, eclipse, code-formatting, tidy

I do like the SQL editor now bundled with Eclipse but I can't seem to find a way for it to format my code like eclipse will with my java.

Did I miss something, or does anybody have any alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This had bothered me in the past, but I shelved it until I saw your question.  The [DBViewer](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/zigen/home/plugin/dbviewer/about_en.html) plug-in seems to do a fairly decent job of this, but I only tested it with basic SQL.  For example, it will transform

```
select * from urbase order by foo;
```

into

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM
        urbase
    ORDER BY
        foo
```

This does the best job out of any that I tested, although there might be better plug-ins out there.